# Rotate reference system align with points position coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I have the {x',y'} coordinates values and I'm trying to rotate this blue coordinate system to get {x'',y''}.

The coordinates of P2 point in {x2',y2'} are {200,200} and I know that the final coordinates in {x2'',y2''} are {282.84,0}.

I have calculated the slope of the p1-p2 line in order to get {x2'',y2''} but I don't know how to get {282.84,0}

[Description of the problem mentioned aboved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYjIv.png)

So, how could I get the {x'',y''} of the points P2,P3,P4 in the image?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3636045.

Comment: So is it so that you have three different coordinate systems (no prime, one prime and double prime) and four points $P_1$ through $P_4$ that are not really related to the coordinate systems? And you know the coordinates of the points in the first two coordinate systems, and you'd like to know them in the third coordinate system?

Comment: I interpret it so that the transition from the first coordinate system to the second, it doesn't invove any rotation, but a linear translation $10$ units down the $y$-coordinate? Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Can't you simply use the inverse rotation matrix?

Comment: Yes, first transformation is a translation + rotation, the important is the second (x',y') -> (x'',y'').